# Issue with Facebook Login in iPhone apps when My application is installed

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

I have a travel app in which Facebook SDK is integrated for login purpose.
When i install my app in the iPhone and then access other app using facebook, it prompts and opens my application.

We are able to login into our app successfully using Facebook. The issue when other apps are trying to login using Facebook they are redirected to our App instead of Facebook Login Page.

If i uninstall my application then the login in other apps using Facebook is successful.
Only when my application is installed the Facebook always opens my application.

How to solve this issue. Is there any permission which needs to be configured in the plist.

We are using URL scheme for facebook. This is the plist configuration is given below.
I have configured all these in my plist. Not sure if some of these are causing the issue.

Please look into the plist and let me know if i need to remove somethings,

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which facebook sdk you are using? and a reminder in info.plist we need to put our facebook app id under url types of Info section

Comment: Facebook SDK : 3.x and I have updated the Facebook App Id in the URL Section

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513630/how-to-get-email-id-of-user-using-facebook-sdk-4-7-in-ios-9/33513692#33513692

Comment: Hello kb920,  Bhagyalaxmi Poojary.   We are able to login into our app successfully using Facebook. The issue when other apps are trying to login using Facebook they are redirected to our App instead of Facebook Login Page.

Comment: can someone please help me solve this issue...

Comment: You should really add some code here. My best guess is that you are using a custom URL scheme that is also used by another app. This is just from what I heard but iOS would open the app that first registered a custom URL scheme, but not 100% sure

Comment: Hello Bjom, sorry for late reply. I have updated my original post and provided plist configuration