# FacebookSDK not able to login, giving blank white screen after authorization.

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-sdk-4.0

Added URL Type , LSApplicationQueriesSchemes and other settings.

Tried every possible solution, Not able to debug. Please help with this

[image: Not redirected to app after authorization]

Comment: have you used custombutton ?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513630/how-to-get-email-id-of-user-using-facebook-sdk-4-7-in-ios-9/33513692?noredirect=1#comment54811287_33513692

Comment: @coreDeviOS have assign fbsdkbutton to custombutton class? can you post image of "Show identity inspector" of custom button ?

Comment: check if it is iOS 9 specific

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by implementing BOTH of these functions, even though facebook's developer website only lists one:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}

func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
        let shouldOpen :Bool = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
            app,
            openURL: url,
            sourceApplication: options["UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey"] as! String,
            annotation: nil)


        return shouldOpen

}
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone fighting this for swift3 + ios10, make sure your appdelegate looks like:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

[source](http://ashishkakkad.com/2015/05/facebook-login-swift-language-ios/)

Answer (score 1):

If this is helpful for anyone - I had the Facebook login button on a detached controller (specifically within a custom view that presented a separate View Controller). Once I placed the button inside the parent view controller, things worked instantly.