# How does Facebook Login work in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uiwebview

I am developing a hybrid iOS app in my firm. We need to integrate a login screen to our app. We hosted the login by using `UIWebView` and it worked like charm when we used our default login. We are able to maintain the login credentials when we get to the `UIWebView` part of the app, too. But it did not work with Facebook and G+ login. Now we are trying to integrate Facebook and G+ login manually.
My question is, how do we get it to work in a way that we can synchronise the Successful Login case with the server so that a session might be able to hold it when the user reaches `UIWebView` part

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513630/how-to-get-email-id-of-user-using-facebook-sdk-4-7-in-ios-9/33513692#33513692

Answer (score 0):

Use `FBSDKLoginKIt` for Facebook and `Google SignIn` Framework for Google. On successful login, you will be provided with user's details in the form of json response. So you will be able to hold user's details when you will reach `UIWebview`.