# Issue Regarding Giving Permission for Facebook Access

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, social-framework

Actually i Want personal Info of Logged in User, But i get only their Id and UserName.
I have tried getting the permission from the user for connectivity , other than that some more permission for accessing the data is required ,guide me through the same.

```
NSDictionary *options = @{ ACFacebookAppIdKey: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1725978560966525"], ACFacebookPermissionsKey : @[@"email", @"public_profile", @"user_about_me"] };
```

Comment: what are the information you try to fetch for user or user friends

Comment: personal Info that include email, name, Profile pics..

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513630/how-to-get-email-id-of-user-using-facebook-sdk-4-7-in-ios-9/33513692#33513692

Comment: i don't want To Use facebook Sdk i m using only with Social Framework..

Comment: You need to _ask_ for the additional fields, using the `fields` parameter. How specifically that works in your framework – check its documentation.

Comment: Thing is that i am Only getting Id and name of Logged In User. I don't know how Much Privacy concern Is there.. If i use same thing That i have done With Facebook In Twitter I get JSON data..